# IBM Rapid Application Developer 8.5.1 scrollbar not draggable (Enterprise Explorer\Package Explorer) + Ctrl-F on JSP sometimes not working

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, ibm-rad

I currently have IBM Rapid Application Developer 8.5.1 installed on Windows 7 64 bit and I'm having these two issues:

- I'm unable to scroll by dragging the scrollbar with my mouse on both
  the Enterprise Explorer and the Package Explorer. If I do so, it goes
  to the first state. I am able to scroll using the arrows OR by
  clicking under/above the scrollbar OR by using my mouse wheel
- Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to find something in my jsp sometimes doesn't work. When I restart IBM RAD, it works
  again, but it's quite irritating.

Question: is this a bug within RAD (or Eclipse?) or is it a Windows 7 thing?

Answer (score 0):

To make scrollbars draggable under windows 7 64bit:

Preferences\General\Appereance => uncheck "Enable animations" and "Enable colored labels".
The IDE will issue a restart ("yes"...) and scrollbars will be draggable as expected.

I don't think this will impact ctrl+f, though.

In the end, sounds like an incompatibility between desktop compositing and (old) SWT